# How to put a Menu on the left side of a particular page in Wordpress 3.5

Tags: menus

I am creating a website. The website already has a main menu which appears on the top.
But in one of the pages I want a side menu to appear on the left side of that page.

I have gone through many tutorials which say to add some code in `register_nav_menus` in `functions.php` but I cant find any such function in `functions.php`.

I am not able to create the menu. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`register_nav_menus` allows you to create a new menu.

In your `functions.php` you can add this code to create a new menu. Then in your template file we can call the menu. You will most likely need to mess with the css to style the menu and make it look pretty.

```
function our_multipe_menu_setup(){
    register_nav_menus( array( 'our_left_side_menu' => 'Left Side Menu' , 'our_second_menu' => 'Our Second Menu' ) );
}
add_action( 'after_theme_setup', 'our_multiple_menu_setup' );
```

Then in the admin area you should now see a menu under *apperance > menu* that is called `Left Side Menu`.

In your template files, as `index.php`, `page.php` or any other template file, you can display the menu with this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'left_side_menu' ) );
```

There are ways to customize how the menu is displayed but this is the most default and simple way to get the menu.

Wrap it in a `html` element and style the HTML with CSS in your `style.css` file.

I suggest using Firefox and Firebug to inspect your website, helps a lot with styling.

Getting the menu to be on the left side of the page is going to be the HTML and CSS part of the gig.

**!Edit:!**

The first solution I had provided was to create several menus. To create a single menu, this should work:

```
function our_single_menu_setup(){
   register_nav_menu( 'left_side_menu', 'Left Side Menu' );
}
   add_action( 'after_theme_setup', 'our_single_menu_setup' );
```

Comment: i tried adding this function our_menu_setup in the functions.php but the menu did not show up in the appearance-menu section

Comment: I will edit my answer, I tried to make it as simple as possible and over looked register_nav_menus still requires an array.

Comment: I have edited my answer hopefully that helps.

Comment: Happy to help. Please select the Check mark on the left side of my answer to select it as the best answer.